# Como acceder a un archivo alojado en otro servidor

Tags: javascript, html, cors

Estoy intentando acceder a un archivo .obj con javascript que un dominio diferente al que se encuentra alojado, colocando la dirección url de su ubicación pero me retorna el siguiente error "falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin')", tengo los accesos a los archivos de ambos dominios pero no encuentro una forma de utilizarlos sin duplicar los archivos en las dos ubicaciones mi pregunta es ¿Como puedo resolverlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la carpeta donde se encuentran alojados tus archivos podés crear un archivo `.htaccess` con lo siguiente:

```
<FilesMatch "\.obj$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "dominio.com"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Donde `dominio.com` es el dominio desde el cual querés acceder. Con un wildcard `"*"` podés darle permisos a cualquier dominio.

Saludos.